# Checking Null Wrappers against primitive values

Tags: java, expression, wrapper, boxing

```
Integer i = null;
if (i == 3)
```

Why the second line above throws a `NullPointerException`, IMHO, this has only one meaning which is Wrapper Object `i` is to be unboxed which yields the Exception such as:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(null);
int x = list.get(0);
```

EDIT: Can you supply me with some format doc?

Comment: What do you expect the second line to produce?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It throws NPE because compiler does the following "magic" for you:

```
Integer i = null;
if (i.intValue() == 3)
```

Obviously `i.intValue()` throws NPE when `i` is `null`.

Comment: Does this mentioned anywhere in JLS?

Comment: @Muhammad, I believe it is mentioned. But I think that even better way to understand the compiler sugar is to compile code, then decompile it using one of available java decompilers (e.g `jad`) and see the result. You will see similar code there.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to compare a wrapped number with a primitive one, the wrapper is automatically un-boxed. If at that moment, the wrapper is null, you get a NullPointerException. This is one of the common pitfalls of the autoboxing system (the other being poor performance if you box/unbox numbers in a loop)

Answer (score 2):

Think of the wrapper class to be a holder object. Something like:

```
public class Integer {

private int intValue;

//getters and setters

}
```

If the pointer or the reference to the whole object is `null`, you cant get to the value to do any `boxing/unboxing` operations.

When you say:

```
if (i == 3)
```

The `unboxing` occurs automatically on a `null` reference, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't unbox the Integer you would get strange behaviour like

```
Integer i1 = -129;
Integer i2 = -129;
if (i1 != i2)
    System.out.println(i1 +" != " + i2);
```

or

```
Integer i1 = -129;
if (i1 != new Integer(-129))
    System.out.println(i1 +" != " + -129);
```

This prints

```
-129 != -129
```

because the *references* rather than the *values* are different.

Answer (score -1):

This can be avoided checking whether value is null before comparing it.

```
if (dto.getMethod() != null && dto.getMethod() == 0) // Safe check no NPE
```

Following page provides a nice wrapper to avoid to NPE

http://www.javawiki.org/wiki/Avoid_NullPointerException_on_Primitive_Wrapper_Objects