# Checking Integer Wrapper against NULL as well as primitive value 0

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have refer to this before posting this Question.
[Checking Null Wrappers against primitive values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9177585/3425489)

And I have situation that I want to check `Wrapper Integer` with **`null`** as well **`0`**

```
if( statusId != null || statusId != 0 ) //statusId is Integer it maybe 0 or null
    // Do Somethimg here
```

How can I overcome this situation ?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: what do you actually want? if it was about something to do when it is not null or 0 you have already done that.

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh the problem with above code is that it should throw a NPE if statusId **is** null

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes it was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `or` by `and` :

```
if( statusId != null && statusId != 0 )
```

It will work because only if `statusId` is not `null`  :

```
statusId != null
```

you will try to unbox `statusId` to `int`:

```
statusId != 0
```

And in the case of `statusId` is `null`, the short-circuiting `&&` operator will prevent to throw a `NullPointerException`  as `statusId != 0` will not be evaluated.

Comment: More exactly, this will work because of the short-circuiting behaviour of `&&`, the right hand operand (expression) is only evaluated if the left hand operand (expression) yields true. I don't see why people downvote your answer, as it is the most 'natural' way to express the check?

Comment: @user268396 I edited to be more complete. Thank you. Downvotes are very often relevant but not always.

Comment: @davidxxx, this was so simple How can i forget about `&&` operator, thanks

Comment: @shantaram_ You are very welcome. We should know this page by heart ;) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @davidxxx I was just forget about using `&&` since long

Comment: I’d be careful about `statusId != 0`.  I’m pretty sure that is not an unboxing operation, but rather equivalent to `statusId != Integer.valueOf(0)`, which only works because [Integer values in the range -128 – 127 are always reference comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).  The code is safe, but might encourage unknowing programmers to rely on it for values outside that range, for which it would not be safe.

Comment: @VGR   An `Integer` and a primitive `int` are compared with a `!=` operator.  Why do you think that it would not result to an unboxing operation ? Anyway, I have tested and it works with value out of the `-128 _ 127` range and jvm invokes `intValue` to evaluate `statusId` as it generally does when it unboxes Number instances.

Comment: After reading the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) carefully, I’m convinced you are right:  Integer != int causes unboxing followed by numeric comparison.  `!=` is interpreted as a reference equality test only if no other type of comparison is possible.  Though the visual ambiguity would be reason enough for me to opt for something more explicit like `statusId.intValue() != 0`.

Comment: @VGR I get your feeling. It may really be error prone. For my own mind tranquility, I would do the same thing as you in my own code. I answered this morning to a question and it is right that instinctively I didn't provide this way in first intention `Integer i = ...
 if (a==1){...` while it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of `null` check then you can use `equals`, e.g.:

```
Integer i = null;
if(Integer.valueOf(0).equals(i)){
    System.out.println("zero");
}else{
    System.out.println("not zero");
}
```

Comment: Should not use `new Integer(0)` as it create a new object... Use `Integer.valueOf(0)` instead.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thanks for the input, updated the answer.

Comment: @DarshanMehta, here I don't have separate situation for `null` **`OR`** `0`, I have same situation for `null` **`AND`** `0` to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're letting the null through to the second check, and getting a null pointer.

Equivalent working logic:

```
if (!(statusId == null || statusId == 0)) {
}
```

Comment: the `!` operator will be applied to the whole boolean expression `statusId == null || statusId == 0`. So, `if (!(statusId == null || statusId == 0)) {`
 will be true for `statusId` with a `0` value. Suppose `statusId` has the `0` Integer value, it means that `(statusId == null || statusId == 0)` will be evaluated to `false` and the reverse of this evaluation `(!false)` is `true`.

Comment: My try was to avoid `NullPointerException` and it is doing that. thank to you too

Comment: @davidxxx thanks. you made me realise why this was hurting.  I was trying to reproduce the actual boolean logic, and failing.  But now realise the question is flawed.  Your answer is what the OP actually *meant*.  I've posted another pedantic answer which answers what the OP actually *requested* :)

Comment: @Mr Spoon You are welcome. Indeed, the question is not explicit about the need. I have read it multiple times to guess with high probability the OP meaning. You should have edited your first answer. With a horizontal line separator for example. It would make readable your thinkings.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good 'classic' Java answers in this thread already, so for the sake of it... here's a Java 8 one: use [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html).

Assuming `statusId` is an `OptionalInt`, you would write:

`if(statusId.isPresent() && statusId.getAsInt() != 0)`

Or slightly more cryptically, you could do this:

`if(statusId.orElse(0) != 0)`

In this scenario, `statusId` is never set to null; instead it is set to either a `OptionalInt.of(<some int>)`, `OptionalInt.ofNullable(<some Integer>)` or `OptionalInt.empty()`.

The point of this answer is that as of Java 8, the standard library offers convenient [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) and related classes for primitives to write null-safe Java code. You might want to check them out. `Optional` is especially handy, because of its [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) methods.

Comment: but I've not yet used Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Just realised why this question hurt so much. It's *actually* about a typo (if so, @davidxxx's answer is correct). It's not about logical equivalence.

But, for what it's worth.  The question specifically asks for:

```
if( statusId != null || statusId != 0 )
```

i.e.  "If it isn't null" it gets in.  Or "if it isn't zero", it gets in.

So, really, the solution is:

```
if (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact context, but you can consider null-safe methods from Apache Commons Lang, e.g.

```
if (ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(statusId, 0) != 0)
  // Do Somethimg here
```